# Code optimization in Reactjs for multiple events

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The points are:

1. when I enter any number in input so % sign add after the digit.
2. when I delete all numbers, % sign remove and width reset according  entering the value.
3. if number already come from the api so when i click then my focus before % sign .
4. number <=100
   so my functionality is working fine, but the problem is i am using multiple events (onClick, KeyPress, keyUp, onBlur etc) , so how i manage this functionality

```
<div className={`form-control valbox1 dvPercValue`} disabled = {isDisabled ? true : false } onClick={event=>this.focusPerc(event, rowIndex)}>
    <Textbox
      onTextboxChange={e => this.onTextboxChange(e, rowIndex)}
      name="percentage"
      isDisabled={isDisabled}
      value={(value) } 
      maxLength={4}
      refData={(input) => {
          this.myAllocat[rowIndex] = input
      }}
      className = "percValue"
      onInputKeyPress= {event=> this.setWidth(event, rowIndex) }
      onInputkeyUp={ event=> this.setInputValue(event, rowIndex)}
      textBoxWidth= { textBoxWidth }
    />
    { value && <span className="percSign ">%</span> }
</div> 

const textBoxWidth = { 
      width: (value && parseInt(value,10) < 101) ? ((value.length ) * 8) : 0
    };

focusPerc =(e, rowIndex) => {
        if (rowIndex >=0) {
          let searchInput= null;
          const allBox = document.querySelectorAll(".dvPercValue");
          for (let i=0;i<allBox.length;i++) { 
            allBox[i].classList.remove("active");
          }
          if (e.target && e.target.tagName) {
            if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'span' || e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input') {
              e.target.parent.classList.add("active");
              searchInput= e.target.parent.children[0];
            } else {
              e.target.classList.add("active");
              searchInput = e.target.children[0]
            }

          }
          if (searchInput) {
            const strLength = searchInput.value.length * 2;
            searchInput.focus();
            searchInput.setSelectionRange(strLength, strLength);

          }
        }

      }

 setInputValue = (e, rowIndex) => {
    const inputvalue=e.target.value.trim();
    if (e.keyCode ===8 && rowIndex >=0) {
      if (parseInt(inputvalue,10) > 100) {
        return;
      }
      e.target.style.width = ((inputvalue.length ) * 8) + 'px';
    }
  }
  setWidth =(e, rowIndex) => {
    const inputval=e.target.value.trim();
    if (parseInt(inputval,10) > 100) {
      return;
    }
    e.target.style.width = ((inputval.length + 1) * 8) + 'px';
  }

const TextboxComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <input type="text
      value= {props.value}
      name= {props.name}
      maxLength= {props.maxLength}
      className={props.className}
      disabled= {props.isDisabled}
      placeholder= {props.placeHolder}
      onChange={props.onTextboxChange}
      onKeyPress = {props.onInputKeyPress}
      onBlur = {props.onTextBoxBlur}
      ref={props.refData}
      autoComplete="off"
      onKeyUp = {props.onInputkeyUp}
      style = { props.textBoxWidth } 
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: can you please explain what are you trying to do with all your events? and what is TextBox component?

Comment: Can you please explain why do you need so much event for the `<TextBox />` component? Also, could you upload the code for that component, in order to see what are you doing in each event.

Comment: i want to remove and add %sign, when user enter or detete digit, Thats why i am using so many events

Comment: Can't you set the percentage outside the textbox? So it's visually always there, just not part of your textbox? :)

Comment: Although I inlined the first image, it is recommended to give your code as text, and not as images. It is simply easier for people to copy and paste it to play around with than to get all that text copied from reading the images

Comment: Sorry , not able to paste the code here.

Comment: Ofcourse you can, but it could be you have to add a bit more info about what is not working in a textual format. You are the one who wants help, so don't shy away from doing a bit of effort here

Comment: I have added all code. Please suggest me what i do for this.

Answer (score 0):

For optimizing your *ReactJS code* you can firstly divide it into **clear components** and subsequently work on their functionality

So say you want **add/remove** a class *"active"* to your element so that you can highlight the field that the user is currently focused on this can be done as following:

```
<input
  type="text"
  className="simple"
  onFocus={e => (e.target.classList += " active")}
  onBlur={e => (e.target.className = "simple")}
  />
```

Which will help you avoid the current approach (which I guess is like jQuery) where you first capture all the elements and then **loop** over them.

Similarly if you want to capture the whole input of the user and then *replace % sign for the deleted characters* you can use a state for your component updating it through **onChange**.

If it is simply about *showing a % sign* after your input you can continue with your own code `value && <span className="percSign ">%</span>`

Comment: @user3639569 If you can list what is it that you exactly want I might be able to help more. It is not clear from your question at the moment.